# Notation for propriety of elliptic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

Let $ E: y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c $ be an elliptic curve over $Q$ which have discriminant $\Delta\neq 0$ and conductor $N$ 
And we have this notation

$Ord_{2}(\Delta) $ or $ord_{2}(b)$

$V_{l}(\Delta)$

What do we mean by these  two notations above? And what are their roles?

And give an example of them in this curve 
$$E:y^2=x^3-x^2+1$$

Comment: $\text{ord}_p(n)=k$ where $p^k$ is the highest power of the prime $p$ dividing the integer $n$.

Comment: Do you know $p$-adic numbers ? $E/\Bbb{Q}$ embeds into $E/\Bbb{Q}_p$ for each $p$ (which is much easier to understand because of the $p$-adic binomial series for the square root) and for curves over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ the reduction modulo $p$ is well understood. See Silverman's book.